# Window 8 metro Popup with fogging

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a **Popup** in vertical center of the screen (it fills about 1/3 of it) and stretched horizontally with custom content to interact with user. I want to make current frame fade into gray when popup is shown just like **MessageDialog** does (still can't post image for example)

There is some workaround with **DoubleAnimation** object applying to **Windows.Current.Content** but the result is slightly different from **MessageDialog**'s fogging.

Is there a standard way to achieve graying out current frame when showing **Popup** like **MessageDialog** does?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah - make the popup take the entire screen and put a Grid below your actual popup that's black and has opacity =~0.5.

Take a look here - full source code for a popup that handles all that (and animation) for you:

http://socialeboladev.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/turn-any-usercontrol-into-a-pleasing-dialogflyout-in-windows-8/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This approach was my next target and your sources helped a lot in the investigation. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: REMEMBER you need to have a CLOSE button if you do this. There is no light dismissal if you obscure the rest of your application from the Popup. Best of luck!

Comment: @JerryNixon With the popup class in the link, all you need is to specify the overlayDismiss flag, and you are good.

Comment: Yeah, Jerry, you are right - I thought about adding Tapped delegate on grayed area to check if user tapped outside the popup's content and delegate for tapping the content itself to set TappedRoutedEventArgs e.Handled = true; to prevent delivering the event deeper in hierarchy tree.

Comment: To Shahar: thanks, I will look at overlayDismiss flag. Think it can make a trick for me